# Odata $OrderBy and $Top not working with $Apply functions

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to add an $orderBy and $top operator to my Apply function in order to return the top 5 counts but I am getting unexpected errors. This is how I read that it should be formatted.

`https://localhost:5001/v2.0/TableName?$apply=groupby((Column1),aggregate($count as Count))&$orderby=Count desc&$top=5` 
I get error: `"Message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'Count' on type '.....Models.TableName'."`

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Moving it inside the brackets like this:
`https://localhost:5001/v2.0/TableName?$apply=groupby((Column1),aggregate($count as Count)&$orderby=Count desc&$top=5)`

I get error: `"Message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Invalid value '5)' for $top query option found. The $top query option requires a non-negative integer value.",`